# Difficulty in Understanding the Points of Incidence in Applications of AM-GM Inequality.

Tags: inequality

The author describes a way to find minimum or maximum values of function through AM-GM Method: [image]

He then goes on to ask the following problem:

[image]

Note that we must solve this problem through the AM-GM Inequality. I have been trying to understand his argument for a long time, but have failed miserably. Please explain his argument. It is given below:

[image]

Comment: Still the minima is at x=3.

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to understand the given proof line by line, or are you trying to understand why the author made the specific choices in the proof? (By the way, just my opinion: while it is certainly possible to make sense of what the author is doing, I think it's a really bizarre way to go about this problem. So don't feel bad if you're having trouble seeing what's going on!)

Comment: I just don't understand what's going on! It would be kind if anyone could explain this solution line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Since x >= 3, the point of incidence is x = 3. In that case,  1/x = 1/3. So we write x as x/9 + 8x/9, and when we apply AM- GM to x/9 and 1/x, since at the point of incidence they're both equal to 1/3, equality holds when applying AM- GM. Furthermore, in 8x/9, we put x = 3 (because of the point of incidence), and we get the desired result.

If this isn't 100% clear, just let me know, I'll be glad to explain it to you thoroughly :)